# "Undefined variable" although it is defined

Tags: php, laravel

This is a view that should show comments on a post. I received the following error, although I have defined `comments`:

> Undefined variable: comments (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\StuffSpot\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

The steps are as follows:

1. This is the line that has the error:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
```

2. The following is the route of the form:

```
<form action="{{route('comment.create')}}" method="post">
```

3. The `comment.create` route:

```
    Route::post('/createcomment', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@postCreateComment',
        'as' => 'comment.create',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
```

4. `PostCreateComment` has some insert code + the following:

```
return redirect()->route('dashcomment')->with(['message' => $message]);
```

5. `dashcomment` route:

```
    Route::get('/dashcomment', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@getDashComment',
        'as' => 'dashcomment',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
```

6. `getDashComment` function:

```
    public function getDashComment()
    {
        $comments = Comment::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return view('dashboard', ['comments' => $comments]);
    }
```

Comment: Use `print_r( get_defined_vars() );` right before the `foreach(){}` loop to verify the available vars.

Comment: That controller code looks right. Are you positive you are visiting that endpoint and that you don't have that `foreach` code in some other blade view?

Comment: The foreach exists in the dashboard blade , which gives error.

Comment: Add a `dd($comments)` line right before `return view` in part 6

Comment: Check `php artisan route:list` and make sure some *other* controller function isn't taking precedence.